# Why REJECT slows nmap?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nmap

Closing ports except 22 and 443. This dramatically slows down the nmap scans:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

If I remove the REJECT rule, nmap is fast.

So how to make other ports look like closed ports without slowing down the nmap?

Comment: I'm surprised that this response slows down `nmap` but I don't get why you worry about the speed that people can do a port scan on your machine.  Normally, when (and if) possible, it is best to make it as bad as possible.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I'm a developer, so it needs to be as good as possible for debugging things. There are some unwanted open ports, I'd like to see them as 'closed' (and at the same speed as without iptables). Can't the iptables just simulate what the OS does when a closed port is scanned?

Comment: This is actually supposed to be the same, which is why I find it weird.  I don't have time to test it now but will follow your question and probably do some tests tonight.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, it's probably the rejection type. `tcp-reset` works.

Comment: https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html#idp47152076248992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the 'tcp-reset' reject type that does what the OS normally does with the closed ports:

```
-A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: [to elaborate on "why":](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html) "Linux limits the rate of ICMP error packets to each destination.

Comment: @sourcejedi, same thing if you remove the limit. The slowdown is probably because of the ICMP error packets themselves.